# How can I find the <div> element that belongs to this button

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to convert my program into plain javascript and remove all JQuery code, however I used to use a JQuery function like this to find the  with the class ".hide-this" to only hide the Card-Body of the Card belonging to the button.

```
  /* Collapse/Expand Card-Content in ListAction*/
  $('.btn-hide').click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.card')
      .find('.hide-this')
      .toggle();
    if ($(this).text() == 'Zuklappen') {
      $(this).text('Aufklappen');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Zuklappen');
    }
  });
```

But when I try to do this in plain javascript I always get an error that this.closest is not a function

I assume that this doesn't refer to the element the actionListener is added on, but I don't know how to refer to this element either

```
const toggleCard = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-hide');
  toggleCard.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const hide = this.closest('.hide-this');
      hide.style.display = hide.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `this.closest` to `elem.closest`

You can see it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/xxKEoqN?editors=1010)

Ps: Also use `window.getComputedStyle(hide).display` instead of `hide.style.display`, to check if elem is visible or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I doesn't work in my case specifically because the Buttons that "toggle" the hide-this div are not in the div it self but after it.

So I assume that elem.closest doesn't find it because its not a parent element of the button right? Is there any way around this?

Comment: @ArvidStrauß use `previousElementSibling` to get prev element, like this: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/vYByJpW

Comment: @ArvidStrauß there is also `.prev` in jquery, in the case it wasn't directly next to it: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: thank you very much...this previousElementSibling is very helpful and I now understand that I need to practice the DOM Navigation via parent, child, sibling relationships etc...thx again

Comment: @ArvidStrauß no problem. yes, its called dom navigation or traversing, and here is tutorials for it:

link1: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp 

link2: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp 

link3: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_traversing.asp